# What is the design technique in the LocalDate.format() and LocalDate.parse()

Tags: design-patterns, java-8, design-principles, java-time

In the `java.time.LocalDate` of Core Java 8, the `format` method is implemented as the following:

```
@Override  // override for Javadoc and performance
public String format(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(formatter, "formatter");
    return formatter.format(this);
}
```

Similarly, the static `parse` method is implemented as the following:

```
public static LocalDate parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(formatter, "formatter");
  return formatter.parse(text, LocalDate::from);
}
```

This is different from *composition* or *aggregation* because, `LocalDate` is *immutable*, and thus adding an instance variable to the `LocalDate` object would break the *immutability*. From the aspect of responsibility, it doesn't seem to be *delegation*, either, according to the book [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672), where the delegation also requires a corresponding instance variable

**Question: What design technique or pattern is applied? is it just the weakest dependency? or also a *delegation*? or something else?**

Comment: It’s not composition or aggregation, but it definitely is delegation. But what actual programming problem does giving the thing a name solve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is good design technique in the design of immutable objects

Comment: @Rui hmmm how is delegation good for that? Immutability means to retrict access to data

Comment: @Eugene IMO, the design of `LocalDate.format()` and `LocalDate.parse()` is dynamic in that the given `LocalDate` instance can be *formatted* or *parsed* depending on the `formatter` parameter, say when calling the `format` or `parse` during different time different `formatter` can be given to get different result, and the *immutable* feature of `LocalDate` keeps valid in any case. So I said the relationship between `LocalDate` and the `DateTimeFormatter` is *weak dependency* and *delegation*